# How to type property based on other prop with Typescript and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How to make an intelligent prop type? I have Alert component which has some actions. Those actions can be clickable, there are some different components like Button or Link.

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
<Alert actions={[{ component: Link, props: { /* here only Link props available */ } }]} />
```

and

```
<Alert actions={[{ component: Button, props: { /* here only Button props available */ } }]} />
```

So props property should determine its type based on component property. Is this possible? I do not want to add any additional generics like

```
<Alert<ButtonProps> ... />
```

it should be "intelligent" and do it automatically

Comment: Are you going to pass any arbitrary functional component to `component`, or do you have a subset of union types, e.g. `typeof Button | typeof Link`?

Comment: I would like to have possibility to pass there only Button or Link component. But the most important is that if i pass there someting like component: Foo, I will be able to call it in Alert like <Foo /> with FooProps passed in props attr

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by generics, but it can get a little bit complicated: you need to explicit start which components are to be accepted by `<Alert>` via its prop type:

```
interface AlertAction<TFunctionalComponent extends FC<any>> {
  component: TFunctionalComponent;
  props: ComponentPropsWithoutRef<TFunctionalComponent>;
}

interface Props {
  actions: Array<AlertAction<typeof Link | typeof Button>>;
}

export const Alert: FC<Props> = ({ actions }) => {
  // Alert component body here
};
```

However I do see this as an anti-pattern: instead of splitting the component name and props into two separate keys, what if you simply let `actions` accept an array of ReactElement? i.e.:

```
interface Props {
  actions: ReactElement[];
}

const Alert: FC<Props> = ({ actions }) => {
  return <div>
    {actions.map(action => <>{action}</>)}
  </div>;
};

const MyApp: FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {/* Will work */}
      <Alert actions={[<Link {...linkProps} />]} />
      <Alert actions={[<Button {...buttonProps} />]} />
    </>
  );
};
```

If you need to update the props or inject some custom child node into these elements, then you can take advantage of [React.cloneChildren](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/cloneElement):

```
const Alert: FC<Props> = ({ actions }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {actions.map((action) => (
        <>
          {cloneElement(action, {
            children: <>Custom child node for action elements</>,
          })}
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but in example you put I have no control over what will be in the actions array. It should be always Link or Button, not Link and Button and something else.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't allow you to narrow types based on specific functional components. There is another solution I have in mind but I'm not sure if that's what you want or what are the requirements. If you have time, create a basic [mcve] snippet on Codesandbox and I can tinker with it.